# How to declare variables with a type in Lua

Tags: oop, variables, types, lua

Is it possible to create variables to be a specific type in Lua?

E.g. `int x = 4`

If this is not possible, is there at least some way to have a fake "type" shown before the variable so that anyone reading the code will know what type the variable is *supposed* to be?

E.g. `function addInt(int x=4, int y=5)`, but x/y could still be any type of variable? I find it much easier to type the variable's type before it rather than putting a comment at above the function to let any readers know what type of variable it is supposed to be.

The sole reason I'm asking isn't to limit the variable to a specific data type, but simply to have the ability to put a data type before the variable, whether it does anything or not, to let the reader know what type of variable that it is supposed to be without getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do this, would be by creating a custom type in C.

[Lua Integer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484437/lua-integer-type)

Comment: I know that each variable has a type, but is there a way to put something before the variable name without causing an error, such as foo x = 5? I don't need the fake "type" to do anything, but I'd like to have it there so I know what types my variables should be when I'm looking at my functions. Sorry if I was unclear in my post.

Comment: Thanks! I found that the OP of the thread you linked had used a = int(5), and that achieves what I was wanting to do. I didn't necessarily need the type to be before the variable name -- I just wanted it there to display the type for reference.

Comment: Creating a custom type in Lua doesn't change the syntax. That thread is about creating a new type with custom behavior, but the variables are as untyped as ever. However, if the syntax `a = int(5)` is acceptable then it's easy enough to make that work without making custom types. @EchoFive

Comment: @bames53 Yeah, but that `int` truly is an integer, not a floating point number, perhaps the OP wanted that as well.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using comments:

```
local x = 4 -- int

function addInt(x --[[int]],
                y --[[int]] )
```

---

You can make the syntax `a = int(5)` from your other comment work using the following:

```
function int(a) return a end
function string(a) return a end
function dictionary(a) return a end

a = int(5)
b = string "hello, world!"
c = dictionary({foo = "hey"})
```

Still, this doesn't really offer any benefits over a comment.

Comment: "I find it much easier to type the variable's type before it rather than putting a comment..." I know I can comment, as stated in my post -- I'm just wanting to know if having a "fake" data type before variables is possible.

Comment: @EchoFive My example is intended to show that you could use a strict format. Your suggestion implies something like `--[[ this function takes a couple ints ]] function addInt(x, y)` whereas I'm sort of extending the syntax: `function addInt( --[[int]] x, --[[int]] y)`.

Comment: @EchoFive Just examining the [Lua grammar](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#8) will tell you that comments are the only thing you can insert in these locations.

Answer (score 0):

No. But I understand your goal is to improve understanding when reading and writing functions calls.

Stating the expected data type of parameters adds only a little in terms of giving a specification for the function. Also, some function parameters are polymorphic, accepting a specific value, or a function or table from which to obtain the value for a context in which the function operates. See [string.gsub](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub), for example.

When reading a function call, the only thing known at the call site is the name of the variable or field whose value is being invoked as a function (sometimes read as the "name" of the function) and the expressions being passed as actual parameters. It is sometimes helpful to refactor parameter expressions into named local variables to add to the readability.

When writing a function call, the name of the function is key. The names of the formal parameters are also helpful. But still, names (like types) do not comprise much of a specification. The most help comes from embedded structured documentation used in conjunction with an IDE that infers the context of a name and performs content assistance and presentations of available documentation.

[luadoc](http://www.keplerproject.org/luadoc/manual.html) is one such a system of documentation. You can write luadoc for function you declare.

[Eclipse Koneki LDT](http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/ldt/) is one such an IDE. Due to the dynamic nature of Lua, it is a difficult problem so LDT is not always as helpful as one would like. (To be clear, LDT does not use luadoc; It evolved its own embedded documentation system.)

[image]